# Insert Date in Access DB - zero date

Tags: java, sql, date, ms-access

I'm making a library project in Java that is supposed to record data about members, books, users and borrowings. When I create a new object of the class Borrowing the system automatically notes the IssueDate. 
The problem happens when I try to make a record of the book being returned with and UPDATE SQL QUERY and record the ReturnDate.The query works but in DB in the corresponding field I always get 30/12/1899 as a ReturnDate.
The SQL query goes like this:

```
UPDATE Booking SET Returned = 1, ReturnDate = "+ sdf.format(getReturnDate()) +" WHERE BookingID =" + getBookingID()    

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
setReturnDate(new Date());
```

I decided to format it to String and format dd/mm/yyyy because that is the format Access recognizes when I enter it manually and it worked with all other queries (like creating a new Booking and IssueDate) in the project and it enters the real date.

I have already tried using java.sql.Date instead, switching to the US format (mm/dd/yyyy) and using # (hash marks) at the beginning and the end of the date string and none of those worked. 
Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Consider using a `PreparedStatement` instead, see [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for more details

Comment: Doesn't the formatted text need to be quoted or escaped?  Actually, just use a `PreparedStatement` and `setDate` on the required column and let the JDBC driver deal with it

Comment: That makes a nice change...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a `PreparedStatement` instead, see [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for more details

Instead of setting the "text" of the query, use [`setDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setDate(int,%20java.sql.Date)) of the `PreparedStatement` and let the JDBC driver work it out